# Permissions Issue When Pulling from GitHub

Tags: linux, git, github

I have cloned a GitHub repository into a new directory on my local machine using:

```
git clone git@github.com:*****/project.git destination-dir
```

Clone worked fine but whenever I try to pull or push I git this error back:

```
error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database .git/objects
fatal: git write-tree failed to write a tree
```

What have I done wrong? And how can I fix this. From what I read so far online, the problem is trivial if you are using your own repository (i.e. not GitHub) but what should I do if this on GitHub (there is no ssh access).

Also, I should add that I have another directory on my machine pointing to same repository on GitHub which is fine for pulls and push.

Comment: may be there un-merged conflicts. Can you try git mergetool?

Comment: Thanks for replying maximus. I can't answer my own question but what I did was reset the permissions on the local copy- actually by using via chown (i.e. chown -R login:group projectDir/).  Thanks again.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow, you can answer your own question. Just answer needs to be helpful enough for the others.

Comment: Thank you.  Will so do later on, got to wait some 7 hours first though lol.  In the mean time anybody can double check my solution and present their answer below which, if it is worthy, I'll choose. Free points here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't look like related to GitHub per-se.

From what you say in the comments, it seems that the write permissions inside the hidden `.git` folder (which contains all of your local git repository data) were not corresponding to the permissions that your git client had when you ran it.

It can be that you cloned the repository with one user account (or using `sudo`), but where trying to pull/push from a different user. If that wasn't the case, something could have messed your local files permissions while cloning.

As you stated, doing `chown -R login:group projectDir/` fixed the problem because it recursively reset all permissions in your project folder (including those of the `.git` folder and its contents).

---

A good experiment would be trying to clone the same repo to a different folder to see if the problem reoccurs. If it does, maybe something is wrong with your default permission usermask and/or your git client permissions.